# NumberRenderer Ext JS 4

Tags: extjs

How I can apply on Ext a number renderer format to a number field like **1233453455647895** to split it in 4 blocks, like this **1233-4534-5564-7895**

Any answer will be apreciated

The solution (thanks to @newmount and @Rajinder) is (Edited at 24/10/2013)

```
flex: 1,  
dataIndex: 'IdMoviCaja',  
text: 'Id',  
renderer: function (value){  
    if (Ext.isEmpty(value)) return value;  
    else {  
        value = value.toString();    
        //Remove existing hyphen first  
        var rg = /([-])/g;  
        value = value.replace(rg, "");    

        //Insert hyphen  
        var re = /(\d{4})(?!$)/g;  
        value = value.replace(re, "$1" + "-");    

        return value;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about using hyphen in number field, but you could use textfield and validate it.
Regarding formatting see this fiddle : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/155
(formatting happens on blur)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this format is available in extjs. So, you have to write custom logic in column renderer like this:

```
    renderer: function(value){
        //custom logic to parse value and format it according to your requirement
        return formattedString;
   }
```